# Oracle Join a Million Record Table slow down query performance

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

My requirement is to find the idle period for the each customer.To find the idle customer first i have to fetch the
registration table and it has 1 million records. To find out the last transaction time for each customer i have to 
join the transaction log table it has 60 million records.Below is my query for that.

```
SELECT CUSTOMERNAME,MOBILENUMBER,ACCOUNTNUMBER,
   CUSTOMERID,LASTTXNDATE, 
   FLOOR(SYSDATE - to_date(TO_CHAR(LASTTXNDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')) AS "IDLE DAYS" 
FROM REGN_MAST
LEFT JOIN 
 ( SELECT TXNMOBILENUMBER,MAX(TXNDT) AS LASTTXNDATE 
   FROM TXN_DETL 
   GROUP BY TXNMOBILENUMBER
 ) 
ON MOBILENUMBER=TXNMOBILENUMBER;

explain plan for
SELECT CUSTOMERNAME,MOBILENUMBER,ACCOUNTNUMBER,
   CUSTOMERID,LASTTXNDATE, 
   FLOOR(SYSDATE - to_date(TO_CHAR(LASTTXNDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')) AS "IDLE DAYS" 
FROM REGN_MAST
LEFT JOIN 
 ( SELECT TXNMOBILENUMBER,MAX(TXNDT) AS LASTTXNDATE 
   FROM TXN_DETL 
   GROUP BY TXNMOBILENUMBER
 ) 
ON MOBILENUMBER=TXNMOBILENUMBER;


Plan hash value: 403296370

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                            | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                     |                           |  1231K|   102M|       |  1554K  (1)| 05:10:59 |       |       |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER               |                           |  1231K|   102M|    58M|  1554K  (1)| 05:10:59 |       |       |
|   2 |   VIEW                               |                           |  1565K|    40M|       |  1535K  (1)| 05:07:07 |       |       |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                     |                           |  1565K|    37M|  2792M|  1535K  (1)| 05:07:07 |       |       |
|   4 |     PARTITION RANGE ALL              |                           |    80M|  1926M|       |  1321K  (1)| 04:24:24 |     1 |1048575|
|   5 |      PARTITION HASH ALL              |                           |    80M|  1926M|       |  1321K  (1)| 04:24:24 |     1 |     4 |
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL              | TXN_DETL                  |    80M|  1926M|       |  1321K  (1)| 04:24:24 |     1 |1048575|
|   7 |   PARTITION RANGE ALL                |                           |  1231K|    70M|       | 12237   (1)| 00:02:27 |     1 |1048575|
|   8 |    PARTITION HASH ALL                |                           |  1231K|    70M|       | 12237   (1)| 00:02:27 |     1 |     4 |
|   9 |     TABLE ACCESS BY LOCAL INDEX ROWID| REGN_MAST                 |  1231K|    70M|       | 12237   (1)| 00:02:27 |     1 |1048575|
|  10 |      BITMAP CONVERSION TO ROWIDS     |                           |       |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|  11 |       BITMAP INDEX FULL SCAN         | IDX_REGN_MAST_7           |       |       |       |            |          |     1 |1048575|
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("MOBILENUMBER"="TXNMOBILENUMBER"(+))

Note
-----
   - dynamic sampling used for this statement (level=11)

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This query takes more than 25 minutes.How to improve the performance of this query.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!!!!

Comment: Did you index columns used in the joining operation? Why all those TO_DATE / TO_CHAR? Can't that be simplified to `sysdate - lasttxndate as "idle days"`?

Comment: yes, i have an index for mobile number and transaction date

Comment: lasttxndate is date time so i am converting to date before calculation

Comment: You should index MOBILENUMBER and TXNMOBILENUMBER columns. If LASTTXNDATE is "date time", just TRUNC it, i.e. `trunc(sysdate) - trunc(lasttxndate)`

Comment: @Littlefoot, Thanks i will calculate the difference using trunc.I have index for both MOBILENUMBER and TXNMOBILENUMBER but the query is still slow

Comment: Indexes are not needed here. There are two full table scans while hash is calculated. Then hash join of two tables. If both tables are big 25 mins are reasonable time.

Answer (score 1):

Your query uses all data from both tables, so the first choice is to chect the execution plan using the `FULL TABLE SCAN`.

Remember `FULL TABLE SCAN` is slow, but selecting **all rows** from a table with an `INDEX` is much slower...

So you should approach an execotion plan as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name      | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |           |  1000K|    60M|       |   176K  (2)| 00:00:07 |
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER     |           |  1000K|    60M|    41M|   176K  (2)| 00:00:07 |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | REGN_MAST |  1000K|    29M|       |  1370   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   VIEW               |           |  1014K|    30M|       |   170K  (2)| 00:00:07 |
|   4 |    HASH GROUP BY     |           |  1014K|    16M|  1610M|   170K  (2)| 00:00:07 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL| TXN_DETL  |    60M|   972M|       | 49771   (1)| 00:00:02 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - access("MOBILENUMBER"="TXNMOBILENUMBER"(+))
```

Depending on your HW and memory configuration the time will vary, but on a recent HW I'd expect elapces time below 10 minutes.

You may further limit it using

a) parallel query

b) keep a materialized view holding the last transaction date

Here my test with generated data leding to 5+ minutes (see below).
So my advice either remove all indexes or hint the `FULL` and retry.

```
SQL> set timi on
SQL> set autotrace traceonly
SQL> SELECT CUSTOMERNAME,MOBILENUMBER,ACCOUNTNUMBER,
  2     CUSTOMERID,LASTTXNDATE,
  3     FLOOR(SYSDATE - to_date(TO_CHAR(LASTTXNDATE, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),'DD/MM/YYYY')
) AS "IDLE DAYS"
  4  FROM REGN_MAST
  5  LEFT JOIN
  6   ( SELECT TXNMOBILENUMBER,MAX(TXNDT) AS LASTTXNDATE
  7     FROM TXN_DETL
  8     GROUP BY TXNMOBILENUMBER
  9   )
 10  ON MOBILENUMBER=TXNMOBILENUMBER;

1000000 rows selected.

Elapsed: 00:05:42.23
```

**Sample Data**

```
create table REGN_MAST
as 
select 
'Name'||rownum CUSTOMERNAME,'00'||rownum MOBILENUMBER, 99*rownum ACCOUNTNUMBER, rownum CUSTOMERID 
from dual connect by level <= 1000000;

create table TXN_DETL
as 
with cust as (
select 
'00'||rownum TXNMOBILENUMBER 
from dual connect by level <= 1000000),
trans as (
select  DATE'2018-01-01' + rownum  TXNDT
from dual connect by level <= 60)
select TXNMOBILENUMBER, TXNDT
from cust CROSS join trans;
```

Comment: Marmite Bomber,Thanks, after using parallel the execution time comes down to 37 minutes.is it possible to reduce further.because the full table scan in the. Registration alone taking all the time.is it possible to speed up the full table scan with the hint?

Comment: @Madhesh I can only recommend - perform my example with generated data (same size as yours) in a development instance. See the elapsed time and execution plan (it took **less than 6 minutes** in my moderate HW). Compare this setup with your production (table size, execution plan, elapsed time).

Answer (score 0):

I would try rewriting the query as:

```
SELECT m.CUSTOMERNAME, m.MOBILENUMBER, m.ACCOUNTNUMBER,
       m.CUSTOMERID, t.TXNDT, 
       FLOOR(SYSDATE - TRUNC(TXNDT)) AS IDLE_DAYS 
FROM REGN_MAST m JOIN 
     TXN_DETL t
     ON m.MOBILENUMBER = t.TXNMOBILENUMBER
WHERE t.TXNDT = (SELECT MAX(t2.TXNDT) FROM TXN_DETL t2 WHERE m.MOBILENUMBER = t2.TXNMOBILENUMBER);
```

Then, be sure that you have an index on `TXN_DETL(TXNMOBILENUMBER, TXNDT)` for performance.

I changed the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN` under the assumption that all customers have transactions.

This also simplifies the date arithmetic.  That has less to do with performance than readability.

Comment: This query works fine if limited to few customers. Applied to all 1M customers index access would lead to elapsed time an hour (Assumption: half of the index blocks are not in the memory; 100 disc access / second). Oracle therefore 1) ignores the index, 2) performs a HASH Join full scanning both tables 3) followed by a `WINDOW SORT`. (My test with synthetic data on 12.1.0.2.0). The intuition suggest and my results shows that the `HASH GROUP BY` performed *before* the join and joining only two 1M row sources **outperforms** the `WINDOW SORT` on the full 60M row source resulting from the join.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber . . . I would not expect an index with 60 million rows and these two columns to overflow memory.  The whole index should fit easily into memory.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thanks, after rewriting the query as you suggested, Transaction table uses the index but Registration table going for full scan and showing 229 hours in the execution plan. Is there any way to avoid the full scan in Registration

Answer (score 0):

Create a covering index on `TXN_DETL(TXNMOBILENUMBER,TXNDT)`.

According to the execution plan 86% of the cost is for the full table scan on TXN_DETL.  If there is an index on all the relevant columns Oracle can use that index as a skinny table.  An `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` operation might run significantly faster than `TABLE ACCESS FULL`.

Comment: ,After creating covering index the execution plan uses the index for Transaction table.But the Registration table full table scan takes 4 hour.Is there any way to avoid full scan in Registration.

Comment: 4 hours to scan 1 million rows seems unusually slow.  Perhaps the time is spent in a bad join.  Instead of us guessing about which operation in the execution plan is slow it would help to generate a Real-Time SQL Monitor report.  The report will tell us exactly how long the operations are taking so we know which part to focus on.  To generate the report, first find the SQL_ID in GV$SQL by filtering the SQL_FULLTEXT column.  Then run this statement and post the entire results in the question.  `select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => 'enter SQL_ID here', type => 'text') from dual;`.

Comment: The report ages out relatively quickly so you may need to run the original statement again to generate monitoring data.

Comment: Thank you very much I will generate the sql monitor report and update the question with that report